# how to install magic uv addon

Tags: add-on

How can I install the magic uv addon?
I have the zip file and I have unzipped the file
What do I do next?
Do I have to copy the complete unzipped file or just uv_magic_uv folder in blender addon folder?  How do I activate it? I can't find the addon in the search also.

Addon download [here](https://github.com/nutti/Magic-UV/wiki/Installation)

Can you please show me how to do this on a clear and detailed step by step answer?
Thanks

Comment: No need to unzip the file. Just open the user preferences and select "install from file", select the zip file and enable it.

Comment: @cegaton Yes i have done it but i cant find the addon in search to activate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- First unzip the file. You'll have a folder with .py files in it.
- Then go to the "scripts" folder in your blender installation directory.
- In the "scripts" folder you'll find another folder named "addons". Open that.
- Then copy the folder you have unzipped in to this "addons" folder.

You're done. Now all you need to do is open Blender and go to File -> User Preferences. Go to the "Add-ons" tab and search for it and it'll be there. Make sure the "Community" supported level is turned on.

[image: Blender User Preferences]

Comment: Or you can click the _Install from File_ button in the _Add-ons_ panel and choose the zip file, and Blender will unzip it to the correct location.

Comment: Thanks it work few moment ago. Actually i need a automatic uv mapping addon. Is there any addon?

Comment: @atek I have no information on that